# Codeigniter uploads same file twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

So i'm uploading any image file via my great upload form and it uploads it twice (ex. name, name1). Code in the model function responsible for upload below:

```
function do_upload () {  
    if(isset($_POST['media'])) {  
        $config = array(  
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf',  
            'upload_path' => $this->path;  
        );  
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);  
        $i = 1;  
            while($i < ($this->input->post('value')+1)) {  
                $this->upload->do_upload('attachment'.$i);  
                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('attachment'.$i)) echo $this->upload->display_errors();  
                echo "added attachment".$i."<br/>"; 
                $i = ++$i;  
        }  
    } else { echo "nothing passed"; }  
}
```

in chrome developer tools i see normal post request send with files i upload, but it created them doubled in the folder. any ideas?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the $this->upload->do_upload method twice in your while loop. Remove the first line before the if statement.

Comment: thank you! my mistake :)   haven't thought it will be actually executed in the if statement!